# adding items to a room, undefined type error

Tags: java

EDIT: In case im not being clear (Sorry im a beginner at Java), im simply just trying to add the possibility of adding items into rooms, however, i want the items aspect to be in its own class, like it currently is. Although in its current sate, it doesn't work.

im trying to make items appear in rooms for my game, so i've made a separate items class, where the relevant code for this is

```
public class Items 
{

private String itemDescription;
private int itemWeight;
/**
 * Add an item to the Room
 * @param description The description of the item
 * @param weight The item's weight
 */
public void addItem(String description, int weight) 
{
    itemDescription = description;
    itemWeight = weight;               
}

/**
 * Does the room contain an item
 * @param description the item
 * @ return the item's weight or 0 if none
 */
public int containsItem(String description) 
{
    if (itemDescription.equals(description)) 
    {
        return itemWeight;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

/**
 * Remove an item from the Room
 */
public String removeItem(String description) 
{
    if (itemDescription.equals(description)) 
    {
        String tmp = itemDescription;
        itemDescription = null;
        return tmp;
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("This room does not contain" + description);
        return null;
    }
}



public String getItemDescription() 
{
    return this.itemDescription;
}

public void setItemDescription(String itemDescription) 
{
    this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
}

public int getItemWeight() 
{
    return this.itemWeight;
}

public void setItemWeight(int itemWeight) 
{
    this.itemWeight = itemWeight;
}

public String getCharacter() 
{
    return this.character;
}

public void setCharacter(String character) 
{
    this.character = character;
}
}
```

and in my separate game class, I've tried linking it into my Game class, like so

```
     // initialise room exits
        outside.setExit("north", lab);
        outside.addItem("notebook", 2);
```

like i do with the exits for my game. However, i get an error message

```
The method addItem(String, int) is undefined for the type 
Room
```

here is the room class

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Room 
{
private String description;
private HashMap<String, Room> exits;


/*
private ArrayList<Item> items;
*/
//private HashMap<String, Item> items;
public Items item;

// Characters in the room
private String character; 

/**
 * Create a room described "description". Initially, it has
 * no exits. "description" is something like "a kitchen" or
 * "an open court yard".
 * @param description The room's description.
 */
public Room(String description) 
{
    this.description = description;
    exits = new HashMap<String, Room>();
}

/**
 * Define the exits of this room.  Every direction either leads
 * to another room or is null (no exit there).
 * @param north The north exit.
 * @param east The east east.
 * @param south The south exit.
 * @param west The west exit.
 * @param up The upwards exit.
 * @param down The downwards exit.
 * 
 */
 /**
 * Define an exit from this room.
 * @param direction The direction of the exit.
 * @param neighbor The room in the given direction.
 */
 public void setExit(String direction, Room neighbor)
{
        exits.put(direction, neighbor);
}

public Room getExit(String direction)
{
    return exits.get(direction);

}

/**
 * Return a description of the room’s exits,
 * for example "Exits: north west".
 * @return A description of the available exits.
 */
public String getExitString()
{
    String returnString = "Exits:";
    Set<String> keys = exits.keySet();
        for(String exit : keys) 
        {
            returnString += " " + exit;
        }
    return returnString;
 }

/**
 * @return The description of the room.
 */
public String getDescription()
{
    return description;
}

/**
* Return a long description of this room, of the form:
* You are in the kitchen.
* Exits: north west
* @return A description of the room, including exits.
*/
public String getLongDescription()
{
    return "You are " + description + ".\n" + getExitString();
}

}
```

Game Class, where the rooms themselves are made

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Game 
{

private Parser parser;
private Room currentRoom;
private ArrayList items;
private ArrayList weights;
private int totalWeight;
private final int MAX_WEIGHT = 10;

/**
 * Create the game and initialise its internal map.
 */
public Game() 
{
    createRooms();
    parser = new Parser();
    items = new ArrayList();
    weights = new ArrayList();
    totalWeight = 0;
}

/**
 * Create all the rooms and link their exits together.
 */
private void createRooms() 
{
    Room outside, theatre, pub, lab, office, up, down;

    // create the rooms
    outside = new Room("outside the main entrance of the university");
    theatre = new Room("in a lecture theatre");
    pub = new Room("in the campus pub");
    lab = new Room("in a computing lab");
    office = new Room("in the computing admin office");
    up = new Room("creepy upstairs");
    down = new Room("spooky downstairs");


    // initialise room exits
    outside.setExit("north", lab);
    outside.item.addItem("notebok", 4); 
    outside.setExit("down", down);
    outside.setExit("up", up);
    outside.setExit("west", pub);
    outside.setExit("east", office);

    down.setExit("north", outside);
    up.setExit("south", outside);

    lab.setExit("east", office);
    lab.setExit("south", outside);
    lab.setExit("north", theatre);

    office.setExit("south", lab);

    pub.setExit("east", theatre);
    pub.setExit("south", outside);

    theatre.setExit("south", outside);
    currentRoom = outside;  // start game outside
}

/**
 * Main play routine. Loops until end of play.
 */
public void play() 
{
    printWelcome();

    // Enter the main command loop.  Here we repeatedly read commands and
    // execute them until the game is over.

    boolean finished = false;
    while (!finished) 
    {
        Command command = parser.getCommand();
        finished = processCommand(command);
    }
    System.out.println("Thank you for playing.  Good bye.");
}

/**
 * Print out the opening message for the player.
 */
private void printWelcome() 
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Welcome to the World of Zuul!");
    System.out.println("World of Zuul is a new, incredibly boring adventure game.");
    System.out.println("Type 'help' if you need help.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(currentRoom.getLongDescription());

}
```

i think its because, the class called "Room" doesnt hold any reference to "item", however im unsure how to go about achieving this? Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Comment: How did you define the class `Room`? The method `addItem` is defined in the class `Items`, is it defined in `Room` as well? Post complete code of both the classes.

Comment: @GirishB Hi! thank you for your response, i just added the complete code for both of the classes

Comment: You have no addItem method in the Room class. yet you're calling it, that's your error

Comment: @Stultuske i said in a different comment: sorry, im really new to Java, do you mean simply taking what i have in my items class (The public void addItem) or just a way to reference it? Im really confused on how to do the latter

Comment: you can't add a "reference" to a method in a method. You need to define public void addItem(String name, int number) { } in your Room class, since that's where you call it. Otherwise, you'll need to change that call, but since we don't know what you are trying to do, the best thing we can advise you is to add that method

Comment: @Stultuske i tried updating my post with more relevant code, and an edit trying to better explain how i mean

Comment: @AdamSteele yes, and the answer remains the same, if you want to call addItem on an instance of Room, the Room class needs to contain an addItem method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The method addItem(String, int) is undefined for the type 
Room
```

Because there is no method definition as addItem(String, Item) in your room class. Either Add this function to Room class before trying to call it. Or fix it as shown below

You would be getting compilation error without it.

Seeing your comment, let me suggest you something, but careful as I don't know your exact need.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Room 
{

        public Items item = new Items();
       ...........
```

And in calling class use it like

```
         outside.item.addIem(...)
```

Comment: sorry, im really new to Java, do you mean simply taking what i have in my items class (The public void addItem) or just a way to reference it? Im really confused on how to do the latter

Comment: Dear Adam, everyone was a beginner at some point or time. I am sure you can do it. I tried to add some more context in my answer above. See if it helps. Good luck!

Comment: thank you for being kind, upon reading your suggestion, i think i've noticed an error on my part, i declare new rooms in the Game class, which i did not specify in my post, however i'll add the code to that now. In that class i already have things like "outside = new Room("outside the main entrance") etc. So your above help wouldn't work in the room class i dont think? i added the code im referring to

Comment: May be i got your problem in Toom class... private String item;
Why is it of string type? Shouldn't it be public Items item? Check updated answer

Comment: sorry for double commenting, the error has changed now, instead of The method addItem(String, int) is undefined for the type 
Room ... its now the same, but for type "Items" instead of Room

Comment: You did outside.addItem("notebook", 2); or outside.item.addItem("notebook", 2);? And  public Items item = new Items();.... Can you put your updated code for all 3 classes

Comment: i done outside.item.addItem("notebok", 4); but now the error message has changed into ""java.lang.NullPointerException" on the debug, pointing to that line

Comment: You will need to do public Items item = new Items(); in Room class. Check updated answer if it is acceptable and fixes your problem

Comment: Hello! that didn't throw an error, im unsure if it works as i haven't got a print method to show items in rooms at the moment, let me figure that out and get back to you, thank you so much

Comment: Good luck! I am sure your original problem is resolved with this.

Answer (score 1):

You mix here the Item logic with the Room logic.

1. Your `addItem` function should be the constructor of Item
2. You should have addItem function in the Room class which instantiate a new Item (Probably store it in a List/Hash if you want more than 1 Item in a Room)
3. The `containsItem` method should also be located in the Room class

Comment: 1. So Items Item = new Item; ?? 2/3. i believe i did set up an Array List within room, the code i just posted in my post update had it deleted though as it didn't work